# App failed to start due to Meteor update patch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, reaction-commerce

My app is not starting and I am receiving this message on localhost:3000 but I am unable to update "Meteor update --patch" , when I type meteor update --patch in command line with admin permission , it says invalid command, please let me know if I can overcome this issue.

```sh
=> A patch (Meteor 1.7.0.4) for your current release is available!
   Update this project now with 'meteor update --patch'.
Errors prevented startup:

While processing files with less (for target web.browser):
imports/plugins/included/default-theme/client/styles/main.less:159: Unknown import: {}/node_modules/react-select/less/select.less

While minifying app stylesheet:
module.js:547:15: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
  at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)
  at Object.require (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:1927:34)
  at packages/minifier-postcss/plugin/minify-css.js:52:37
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at getPostCSSPlugins (packages/minifier-postcss/plugin/minify-css.js:51:43)
  at packages/minifier-postcss/plugin/minify-css.js:155:36
  at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at mergeCss (packages/minifier-postcss/plugin/minify-css.js:139:23)
  at CssToolsMinifier.processFilesForBundle (packages/minifier-postcss/plugin/minify-css.js:109:18)


While processing files with less (for target web.browser.legacy):
imports/plugins/included/default-theme/client/styles/main.less:159: Unknown import: {}/node_modules/react-select/less/select.less

While minifying app stylesheet:
module.js:547:15: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
  at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)
  at Object.require (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:1927:34)
  at packages/minifier-postcss/plugin/minify-css.js:52:37
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at getPostCSSPlugins (packages/minifier-postcss/plugin/minify-css.js:51:43)
  at packages/minifier-postcss/plugin/minify-css.js:155:36
  at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at mergeCss (packages/minifier-postcss/plugin/minify-css.js:139:23)
  at CssToolsMinifier.processFilesForBundle (packages/minifier-postcss/plugin/minify-css.js:109:18)


Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
Started MongoDB.
```

Comment: The errors is not caused by the patch notification, although the patch may resolve it. Unfortunately, I have never tried installing meteor on Windows so I can't really help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install dependencies before starting the app:

`meteor npm install`